# Codeigniter access session in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
function login(){
    $data = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('Login');
    } else {
        $result = $this->LoginModel->account_check($data);
        if($result){
            if($result['status'] = 'admin'){
                $isLoggedin = array('user_type' => 'administrator' ,'admin_name' => $result['username'] , 'is_loggedin' => TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata($isLoggedin);
                $this->load->view('admin/homepage'); 
            } else if($result['status'] = 'user'){
                $isLoggedin = array( 'user_name' => $row['username'] , 'user_type' => 'user' ,  'is_loggedin' => TRUE);
                $this->session->set_user($isLoggedin); 
                $this->load->view('user/homepage'); 
            } 
        }
    }
}

function username_check($username){
    $result = $this->LoginModel->username_check($username);
    if($result != TRUE){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check' , 'Username does not exist');
        return FALSE; 
    } else return TRUE;
}
```

MODEL:

```
function username_check($username){
    $query = $this->db->get_where( 'admin' , array('username' => $username))->result_array();
    if(!empty($query)){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $query = $this->db->get_where( 'user_mst', array('username' => $username))->result_array();
        if(!empty($query)){
            return TRUE;
        }else return FALSE;
    }
}

function account_check($data){
    $query = $this->db->get_where( 'admin' , array( 'username' => $data['username'] , 'password' => $data['password'] ))->result_array();
    if(!empty($query)){
        foreach($query as $row){
            $result['status'] = 'admin';
            $result['username'] = $row['username'];
            $result['password'] = $row['password'];
            return $result; 
        }
    } else{
        $query = $this->db->get_where( 'user_mst' , array( 'username' => $data['username'] , 'password' => $data['password'] ))->result_array();
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $row){
                $result['status'] = 'user';
                $result['username'] = $row['username'];
                $result['password'] = $row['password'];
                return $result; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i access the user data, im going to use this to run an if per view if an account is logged in and if it is an admin acc.

I would like to read some opinion regarding how im using the session if i am 100% correct.

Also, i have a question,

This code `<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>`

blocks direct access to the view, prevents view access but not specifically checks if a user is logged in.

How can i utilize this with the session. If its redundant please tell me,

Comment: Regarding the BASEPATH question - you don't. All page access goes through the CI controllers. Check if a user is logged in here and then load the view. You've got the user loggin in session variable so just use that as a check.

Comment: Can you explain more? I wont no longer need base path. hmm, okay.

So basically, ill just check per controller if a user is logged in. Creating a constructor right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter passes data to the view with a second parameter:

```
$this->load->view('user/homepage');
```

doesn't pass any data.

```
$this->load->view('user/homepage', $data);
```

Would pass in a **$data** variable that you could use. (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Another point - I'd consider using the redirect() function after a successful login rather than loading the view you want in the **login** method. Use the URL Helper to do this (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought $session was an special case, like if you set it, its practically embedded in your browser.

Comment: I  sometimes use redirect because of the refresh option.

But load view is somewhat easier, not complicated. 

Has it got to do with security?

Comment: The reason for using redirect is to separate your login method from your application. If you create a new controller which checks for the logged in session variable in the constructor, then every page will automatically check for this. If it fails - point the user to the login page.

Comment: Can you explain? How does redirect separate login method. 

Im trying to learn programming, but i want to program with no excess code/redundancies. If there is something redirect differs from the load view can you tell me?

Comment: Think about it this way. If you're logged in and you want to go to the main page of the site, you have to log in again. However, If you have a class named 'app', go site.com/app to use the site without having to log in again. In the constructor you'd check that the session you've set where the user is logged in is set. If not, redirect back to the login class(site.com/login). We're deviating from the original question now though and this isn't the best place to give a full answer.

Comment: $session is saved already right? I wont need to pass it from controller to controller to check if $session exists(if logged in)

Comment: Let me clarify my confusion.

After i successfully log in, instead of loading the view, i will redirect right? Whats the method? like should i use refresh?

Also, in checking for the session if a user is logged in, i should also use redirect right if its false